# Understanding this deferred syntax and its purpose in the below Angular Material code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

The Autocomplete demo code for Angular Material has the below code that I am trying to understand:

```
function querySearch (query) {
  var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
      deferred;
  if (self.simulateQuery) {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
    return deferred.promise;
  } else {
    return results;
  }
}
```

Specifically, what is the role of the `, deferred` part in `var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states, deferred;`? The `deferred` object has not even been defined by `$q.defer();` at this point.

Comment: @SimpleJ, thanks for looking into this! I have added more code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [`var` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) with a huge initialiser for the `results` variable and no initialiser for the `deferred` variable.

It could equally have been written

```
var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states;
var deferred;
```

or

```
var results, deferred;
results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states;
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't see this myself